# Powershell Get-ADGroupMember does not return list

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

I am trying to utilize PowerShell to audit all of our security group members in AD.  I have been trying to get `Get-ADGroupMember` to work but anytime I try it, it returns the message 'Cannot find an object with identity 'groupName' under: 'DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx'.

Ive tried the following with no luck:

```
$groupNames = 'groupName1' , 'groupName2' , 'groupName3'
foreach ($group in $groupNames) {
   Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $group
}
```

Has anyone successfully compiled a list of group members in security groups from AD and exported them into a .CSV?

Comment: `-Identity` must contain either a `GUID`, `objectsid`, `distinguishedname`, or `samaccountname`. If you are trying, for example `displayname`, it won't work unless it matches `samaccountname`.

Comment: If `$groupnames` contains `name` attribute values, you can query for usable attributes first before processing `Get-AdGroupMember`. For example, `$groups = ($groupNames |% { Get-AdGroup -filter "Name -eq '$_'" }).SamAccountName`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings your first comment was spot on.  I was using the 'Name' rather than the 'samaccountname'  once replaced that, it got me exactly what I needed.  Is it possible to run the Get-ADGroupMember and have it pull the group names from a text file?  

One other thing.  I was able to run the Get-ADGroup function but it has a lot of extra information in it that I really dont need.  Would I use the -filter and specify the samaccountname just to have it export that name?

Comment: Your code logic is the correct way to read from a list. To get a list of `SamAccountNames` from file `file.txt`, you can do `$groupNames = Get-Content file.txt`.

Comment: For some reason, I am still having an issue getting the 'samaccountname' filter to work.

ive tried
get-adgroup -identity samaccountname
get-adgroup -identity 'samaccountname'
get-adgroup -filter 'samaccountname'

Keeps saying that it cannot find an object with that identity

Comment: `Get-AdGroup -Identity 'SamAccountName Value'` or `Get-AdGroup -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'samaccountname value'"` are the syntax choices. The actual samaccountname value must be subsituted for `Samaccountname value`

Comment: so I ran the following:

Get-AdGroup -filter "SamAccountName -eq 'samaccountname value'"  -SearchBase 'OU=Groups,OU=PW,OU=IMCOM,OU=Lewis1,OU=Installations,DC=nanw,DC=ds,DC=army,DC=mil | Out-file c:\users\nicholas.j.nedrow.sa\desktop\ADGroupSAM.txt

It ran without an error but the .txt file that it created shows nothing in it.

Comment: Did you replace `samaccountname value` with something useful to your environment? Using `out-file` alone will not be beneficial here because it does not understand PowerShell objects. It will output everything as if it was formatted as a string. You need to first use `Get-AdGroup ... | Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName | out-file ....`.

Comment: When you say something useful to my environment, do you mean the name of a group?  I was hoping to compile a list of all of the groups in our container so that I could use that to build a audit of what users are in what groups.

Comment: In that case, you only need `Get-AdGroup -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Groups,OU=PW,OU=IMCOM,OU=Lewis1,OU=Installations,DC=nanw,DC=ds,DC=army,DC=mil`.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider when querying AD groups using the `Get-AdGroup*` commands.

1. The `-Identity` parameter only accepts values that match an object's `Guid`, `ObjectSid`, `DistinguishedName`, or `SamAccountName`. If your input is something other than one of those attribute values, you will either need to run another command to retrieve the proper data or change your list.
2. `-Identity` only accepts a single value, which means if you want to supply a list of values, you need to loop through them.
3. `Get-AdGroupMember` does not output as many attribute/value pairs as `Get-AdUser`. You cannot force it to output more attributes than it does. It does not have a `-Properties` parameter like `Get-AdUser`. Sometimes it requires using both commands to get all of the required data.
4. You can send `Get-Ad*` output to CSV using `Export-Csv`. If you do not use any property filtering like with `Select-Object`, the returned property names will be the columns of the CSV. The associated values of the properties will appear in rows with each row representing one returned object. You can choose to either send the entire results of the command once to the CSV or each time the command runs using `Export-Csv -Append`.
5. Use `Select-Object` to only output properties you care about. `Select-Object Property` outputs a custom object that includes only the property `Property` and the value(s) of `Property` for each object returned. If you only want to return the value rather than a custom object, you can use `Select-Object -Expand Property`.
6. `Get-Content` can be used to read a file. If the file contains only a list of values, perhaps `SamAccountName` values, you can use `Get-Content file.txt` to retrieve that list. The list will be an array that can be looped through.
7. Since `Get-AdUser` can be verbose, it is wise to use the `-Properties` parameter to explicitly list any extra properties beyond the default set you want to return. `-Properties *` will return all properties, but that is not best practice.

Given the above considerations, I would do the following:

```
$groupNames = 'groupName1' , 'groupName2' , 'groupName3'

# Alternatively, if you have a file (file.txt) with your group names listed as one group per line
$groupNames = Get-Content file.txt

# The Foreach-Object section is only needed if $groupNames does not contain a valid -Identity value
# The Filter below uses Name attribute as an example because it assumes $groupNames contains Name attribute values. If it contains another attribute, update the filter accordingly.
$SamAccountNames = $groupNames | Foreach-Object {
    Get-AdGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$_'" | Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
}

# Storing the loop output into a variable is efficient provided you have enough memory for the operation.
# Alternatively, you can just pipe the `Get-AdGroupMember` into `Export-Csv -Append` but that could be a lot of writes!
$output = foreach ($group in $SamAccountNames) {
   Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $group # You can use Select-Object here for specific properties
}
$output | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```